# Image Resize problem in jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js

Tags: jquery, image-processing, jquery-plugins

I am using jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js
My Operating System is windows 7 x86

Please provide any additional information below.

When i m using Multi sized images. The small images comes in tile property
here i m attaching the demo file. 
Please solve this prob as soon as possiable.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Vishal chuahn
Mail:vishname18@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

jqFancyTransitions can't resize images automatically, so images that are smaller of holder div size will be tilled and one that are larger will be croped.